# Worker Service not showing in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to learn Worker Service is ASP.NET core 3.0.For that purpose I installed Core 3.0 SDK. SO obviously its showing in my installed SDK list

[image]

Then added new project into my existing solution and selected ASP.NET Core Application and on the next window where to chose Worker Service Template which is not listing. Also in that dropdown its not showing 3.0 as well. 
[image]
Please help

Comment: Try to update your Visual Studio to the newest Version. I think your version is not the current because of the missing 3.1 sdk.

Comment: Thats awesome buddy.. I did an update and yes, its there now.. :) Thanks a lot. btw post it as an answer So I can mark it

Comment: Done. Thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update your Visual Studio to the newest Version. I think your version is not the current because of the missing 3.1 sdk. (see the comment)